# Pyautogui Break Loop

Tags: python, pyautogui

So I'm having an issue of it often ignoring w has been pressed? is there anyway I can make it 100% i assume its loop and not listening to input?

I have tried adding the listener throughout the code but no joy

t=0

while True:

```
if(keyboard.is_pressed("q")):
    t=0
    while t==0 :
        
        if(keyboard.is_pressed("w")):
            t=0
            break
    
        pyautogui.moveTo(798,717)
        pyautogui.moveTo(778,775)
        
        if(keyboard.is_pressed("w")):
            t=0
             break
            
        pyautogui.click()
        pyautogui.moveTo(599,883)
        
        if(keyboard.is_pressed("w")):
            t=0
             break
            
        pyautogui.click(interval=0.76)
        
        if(keyboard.is_pressed("w")):
            print("OK")
            t=1
            pyautogui.moveTo(900,715)
            pyautogui.moveTo(891,776)
            

if(keyboard.is_pressed("w")):
    print("OK")
    t=1
    pyautogui.moveTo(900,715)
    pyautogui.moveTo(891,776)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mouse moves blocks code execution and `is_pressed` not processed.

Looks like you are using [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) module, so you should use `add_hotkey` method instead of `is_pressed`:

```py
import time

import keyboard
import pyautogui

def press_ctrl_c():
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

keyboard.add_hotkey('q', press_ctrl_c)

while True:
    try:
        # Your code with mouse moves
        print('moving mouse')
        time.sleep(5)
    except KetboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work, I think you're on the right track but it still blocks the w press

Comment: It will be blocking anyway, that's how it's implemented. You could try wrapping everything into separate thread/process to make it nonblocking and responsive, but its harder to implement right and it requires more context about your problem

Comment: Also your loop should be `while not should_stop:` instead of `while t==0 :`

Comment: All I want to do is on key press continues to move mouse in a pattern on a loop, on another key press it stops

Comment: @user3518144, I edited my answer, take a look. If it solves your problem, please, consider marking answer as 'accepted'

Answer (score 0):

You can **stop your code** by **active the default FAILSAFE** of pyautogui (when your cursor position is (X=0;Y=0)).

Run this code, then move your mouse to the left above corner of the screen

```
import pyautogui
def live_mouse():
    pyautogui.moveTo(1000,750,2) # You can first do somethings here before live your mouse
    isContinue = True
    while isContinue:
    try:
        if pyautogui.position()[0] == 0 and pyautogui.position()[1] == 0:
            pyautogui.moveTo(0,0) ## if mouse in the left above corner --> raise error via FAILSAFE mode    
        else:
            # Your actions here
            pyautogui.moveRel(-1000,0,2)
            pyautogui.moveRel(1000,0,2)
    except:
        isContinue = False
live_mouse()
```